# userInfo is is empty from Handoff using NSUserActivity

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, handoff

I'm trying to send a string from my WatchKit app:
I can launch the app via the lock screen fine, but when the `continueUserActivity` method is called, `userActivity.userInfo` contains no values, am I missing something here?

-The only value I get is the `activityType`

Watch:

```
- (void)createActivity {
    self.activity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:@"com.myApp.urlSend"];
    [self.activity setUserInfo:@{@"url":self.wake.href}];
    [self.activity setTitle:self.wake.title];
    [self.activity becomeCurrent];
}
```

Phone:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler {

    NSString *url = userActivity.userInfo[@"url"];
}
```

Comment: Are you certain the URL is being passed as an NSString? If there's a chance it's actually an NSURL, that type isn't supported. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/updateUserActivity:userInfo:webpageURL:

Comment: @"url" is an NSString, I should've pointed that out, I'm also not getting the activity.title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just noticed that you are creating the activity yourself. If you check the docs, you'll see that Handoff works a bit differently on the Watch compared to other platforms: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/updateUserActivity:userInfo:webpageURL:

You just need to call `updateUserActivity` and add your `userInfo` dictionary in that call.

Comment: Wow - this was really hidden in the docs... thanks for that link!